# react native npm start not working as it should

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

i have a react native app and when i run it using `npm start` it doesn't generate a QR code as usual instead it gives me this

```
To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: are you using Expo?

Comment: There is no problem. This is what you will see if you start the bundler in a react native project that uses the react native cli. The QR code shows up in projects using expo. If you're using the react native cli you start the bundler in one terminal instance and for example run `npx react-native run-android` in another terminal instance. https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.61/getting-started.

Comment: did you find, how to run the application in device or emulator? @jayzee